# Nothing can access internet except IE

Tags: firefox, internet, internet-explorer, kaspersky

My partner's Computer is connect to internet and the network Icon shown on the taskbar is also shows it's working. He only use IE to connect to the Internet, nothing else.

Problem started when I install Kaspersky Internet Security on his computer. I try to active the software but it said check your internet connection.

I've downloaded Chrome to try visit some sites (IE still working, but I don't like to use it). After install Chrome, it's also cannot open any site and shown the problem with the DNS server (I use the Google DNS service 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

I download Firefox also but again it's not working.

Additionally, I try to access the site "tinhte.vn" by enter the IP i got from Ping, both FF and Chrome show the Error from Cloudflare. Is there any explanation and solution for my case? Thank you.

The computer is Dell Inspiron One 2310 (AIO touch screen)

Comment: what is the error from cloudflare?
if ping is resolving the IP to name - we can rule out DNS. what do you see when accessing google.com via Firefox? can you perform tracert / traceroute to google.com? Is it possible to disable the Antivirus for the time of troubleshooting? Do you have any content filtering rules on your router?

Comment: From cloudflare it said that cannot resolve the ip address (when I paste the IP address of the "tinhte.vn" to it. I can ping to any website, access any website by IE but not Chrome and Firefox. DNS error also shown when i access Google.com from FF (Error from FF not cloudflare). I've disable all the antivirus, firewall but the problem still there.

Comment: Then try removing google DNS server from your configuration and use the other one - preferably your ISP's DNS server - i believe any ISP provides one nowadays.. also `ipconfig /flushdns` might help..

Comment: I have tried this also but it's not working.

Comment: I would remove the software you installed from his computer see if that halpes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all cookies and restart and check IE. If it is still working except other browser, check for firewall configuration settings. Disable all firewalls then check firefox or other browser.

Comment: I've try, IE still working, Disable all the firewall, security software but other browser still cannot connect to the internet.